# How to insert from a CSV file all data that are not already present in the graph database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have a CSV file as below:

```
charecter,type,name,
naruto,ninjutsu,rasengan,
sasuke,genjutsu,sharingan,
kakashi,ninjutsu,chidori,
```

And I have a graphdb with the following data model:

```
(:Attack{name,type}) - [:BELONGS_TO] -> (:Person{name});
```

Let's say this relationship already exists in the database:

```
(:Attack {name: 'chidori', type: 'genjutsu'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:Person {name: 'kakashi'})
```

I need to load data from the above CSV file and insert into the graph, but it should only insert the data that is not already present in the graph. How can I achieve this?

I tried this query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///xyz.csv' AS row
WITH row
MERGE(a:Attack {type:row.type, name:row.name})
with row, a
MATCH(c:Person{name:row.charecter})
with a,c
MERGE  (a) - [r1:BELONGS_TO] -> (c);
```

This is giving duplicate entries for me. Can someone help on this, thanks!

Comment: Create an unique index / constraints to avoid duplicates. Thanks.

Comment: What is being duplicated? Please be precise.

Comment: doesn't look like it would create duplicates (you should have concstraints for uniqueness and fast lookups).

Comment: Thanks @jose_bacoy ,MichaelHunger , as you guys suggested the query was indeed correct but i was missing the constrains part. I did not add any constrains in my db which was causing the anomalies. Once constraints was properly added query worked as expected.